# Can i get help understanding a changing div section with a background image and gradient filter and using click function javascript to change it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div section with a background image with a gradient cover and some text on. I want to control changing this with a java script button. When its clicked it should remove the gradient and show a new div section with different background image no gradient and text. The JQuery underneath is supposed to check whether the first div is showing. and when clicked it should hide the original div and replace it with the new one. I cannot seem to get it working. any help would be appreciated.

```
/*
jQuery event that triggers when the button is pressed
# is an ID jQuery selector, usage:#anyElementId
*/
$('btnClick').on('click',function(){

/*
In CSS, you can check if an element is visible by checking if the property display value is different from none, because if it's value is none, it will not be visible
*/
    if($('call-to-section').css('display')!='none'){
/*    
So, if div call-to-section is visible, the condition will be true
*/
    $('call-to-section2').show().siblings('div').hide();

    }else if($('#call-to-section2').css('display')!='none'){
/*    
Condition to check if call-to-section2 is visible
*/
        $('call-to-section').show().siblings('div').hide();
/*    
If it is, it will show call-to-section and right after that will search for it siblings and hide them with .siblings('div').hide();
*/
    }
});





<!-- Call To Action Section
================================================== -->
<section id="call-to" class="call-to-section">
    <div class="call-to-layer main-gradient"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3 class="wow fadeIn animated">Global Reach & <span>Demographics.</span></h3>
                <p class="wow fadeIn animated">With 3 billion searches per month, YouTubes search 
     volume is bigger than Bing, AOL, Yahoo and Ask.com combined. If YouTube's user base were a 
country, 
     it would be the third largest in the world. It is the worlds largest site for traffic.
                    </p>
                 <button id="btnClick" class="btn btn-default wow fadeInRight hvr-sweep-to-right 
            button-gradient animated " >Have a look</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="call-to" class="call-to-section2" style= "display:none;">
    <div class="call-to-layer main-gradient"></div>
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3 class="wow fadeIn animated">Test & <span>Testing</span></h3>
                <p class="wow fadeIn animated">This is a new text and total differnt background 
                 picture"
                    </p>
                <button class="btn btn-default wow fadeInRight hvr-sweep-to-right button-gradient 
    `           `animated " id="btnClick" >Have a look</button>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</section>
<!-- /.call-to-section -->

* 9. Call To Action Section
--------------------------------- */
.call-to-section {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(../images/low-poly.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 146px;
    padding-bottom: 146px;


}



   .call-to-section2 {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#FFF
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 146px;
    padding-bottom: 146px;
```

Comment: Part of the problem is that you aren't defining the type of selector, e.g. `$('btnClick')` should be `$('#btnClick')` since you are checking for an element with that id. Same with `call-to-section` should be `.call-to-section` because you are looking for an element with that class. `'#call-to-section2'` should be `.call-to-section2`. Fix those errors first and see where you're at. Currently your code has a bunch of errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had corrected and obtained the desired result, There was following error in codes written.
1) Both Div element has the same id #call-to, which is actually not required if required for some other purpose please have a separate id for all Div.
2)both Button element also have the same ID  #btnClick, change it as #btnClick and #btnClick1
I think id can not be the same for two elements. Read the  MDN Web Docs  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Complete Code is available in my Codepen https://codepen.io/sanjayism/full/ExVdKpv

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btnClick").on("click", function () {
    if ($(".call-to-section").css("display") == "block") {
      $(".call-to-section").css("display", "none");
      $(".call-to-section2").css("display", "block");
    }
  });
  $("#btnClick1").on("click", function () {
    if ($(".call-to-section2").css("display") == "block") {
      $(".call-to-section").css("display", "block");
      $(".call-to-section2").css("display", "none");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, This solution is the correct answer. You have been a major help.